# Loading Images into an array using java

Tags: java

I have a card game that I am developing and need to load card images to the screen. I am using ImageIcon and PaintIcon to Print to image. I want the images to be clickable but I dont know how to do this.

The reason I am using PaintIcon is because I want the images to move with with a click of a button.(stack cards to save space, spread to view them all)

I dont know what to search for or were to get started.

If any one can show me sample code or the right direction that would help.

This is the code I used:

```
public class CustomGraphicsDemo2 extends JFrame {

  // Define constances
  private static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 640;
  private static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 480;

  //Array of image cards


  //Handle for the custom drawing panel
  private DrawCanvas canvas;

  private ImageIcon card1, card2, card3,card4;

  //Attributes of Drawing object
  private int x = 100;      // x and y position
  private int y = 100;
  private int size = 50;    
  private int xSpeed = 3;   // moving speed in x and y directions
  private int ySpeed = 5;

  //Constructor to create the UI components
 public CustomGraphicsDemo2() {
  canvas = new DrawCanvas();
  canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT));
  this.setContentPane(canvas);
  this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  this.pack();
  this.setTitle("Custom Graphics Demo");
  this.setVisible(true);

  // Refresh the display at regular interval.
  // Run the display refresh code in its own thread.
  Thread updateThread = new Thread() {
     public void run() {
        while (true) {
           update();   // update the (x, y) position
           repaint();  // Refresh the JFrame, callback paintComponent()
           try {
              // Delay and give other thread a chance to run
              Thread.sleep(50);  // milliseconds
           } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        }
     }
  };
   updateThread.start();   // callback run()
 }

 // Update the (x, y) position of the graphical object
   public void update() {
   x += xSpeed;
   y += ySpeed;
   if (x > CANVAS_WIDTH - size || x < 0) {
     xSpeed = -xSpeed;
   }
   if (y > CANVAS_HEIGHT - size || y < 0) {
      ySpeed = -ySpeed;
   }
}


   //Custom drawing canvas (designed as inner class).
   class DrawCanvas extends JPanel {
   // Custom drawing codes
   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

      super.paintComponent(g);
      setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      g.fillOval(x, y, size, size);  // draw a circle


      //cards being drawn
      card1 = new ImageIcon("Uno Cards/Blue/ EIGHT.png");
      card1.paintIcon(this, g, 50, 100);

      card2 = new ImageIcon("Uno Cards/Blue/FIVE.png");
      card2.paintIcon(this, g, 100, 100);

      card3 = new ImageIcon("Uno Cards/Blue/NINE.png");
      card3.paintIcon(this, g, 150, 100);

      card4 = new ImageIcon("Uno Cards/Blue/EIGHT.png");
      card4.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);

      //Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; //we use this for drawing later. 
      //g2.fill(new drawImage());
      //g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(10,y,size,size));

    }
 }

  // main program
  public static void main(String[] args) {

   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         new CustomGraphicsDemo2();
       }
    });
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your ImageIcon to a JLabel and then add that label to a panel.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(path));
panel.add(label);
```

A better way is to create separate components for each card. Have CardUI extend JComponent

```
class CardUI extends JComponent {
    //... class members ...

    public CardUI(BufferedImage cardPhoto){
        this.cardPhoto= cardPhoto;
    }

    void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(cardPhoto, x, y, this);
    }
}
```

Edit:
Forgot to mention, that now that you have a CardUI class, you can add listeners to it to see if the mouse is on this CardUI.

Comment: I got the images to apear, I just want to know how can I make a card detect an action event.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should use a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) rather than an array.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so you want to see when a user clicks on a card and perform some action. You need to add a MouseListener to your CardUI class.

Here is the sample code I made. Two classes. One is the main panel: Panel, and the other is CardUI which is the UI for cards. The latter displays an image. The former has a null layour manager, otherwise the cards will not be displayed where you want them to, but where the layout manager decides to.

The photo I used is today's google image: http://www.google.ca/logos/2011/Diego_Rivera-2011-res.png and I saved it on C:\im.png

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel {

    private CardUI cui1, cui2;

    public Panel(BufferedImage cardPhoto){
        cui1= new CardUI(cardPhoto,10,10);
        cui2= new CardUI(cardPhoto,10,60);

        setLayout(null);//make sure you dont have a layout manager

        this.add(cui1);
        this.add(cui2);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedImage cardPhoto;
        Panel panel;

        try {
            cardPhoto= ImageIO.read(new File("c:/im.png"));
            panel = new Panel(cardPhoto);

            JFrame f = new JFrame("Card UI Demo");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setSize(250,250);


            f.getContentPane().add(panel);
            f.setVisible(true);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

/**
 * @author eamocanu
 * This class is not thread safe
 */
public class CardUI extends JComponent implements MouseListener {
    private BufferedImage cardPhoto;
    private static int id=0;
    private int myId; //so to name components for the purpose of this sample

    public CardUI(BufferedImage cardPhoto, int x, int y) {
        this.cardPhoto= cardPhoto;
        myId= ++id;

        setBorder(LineBorder.createGrayLineBorder());
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(cardPhoto.getWidth(),cardPhoto.getHeight()));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(cardPhoto.getWidth(),cardPhoto.getHeight()));
            //FYI: setting preferred size has different effects on various systems
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(cardPhoto.getWidth(),cardPhoto.getHeight()));

        //move this component to the right location on the screen
        //Note: this works if there is no layout manager to its parent container
        setBounds(x, y, cardPhoto.getWidth(), cardPhoto.getHeight());

        this.addMouseListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(cardPhoto, 0, 0, this);
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getX() >= 0 && e.getX()<cardPhoto.getWidth()
                && e.getY() >= 0 && e.getY()<cardPhoto.getHeight()){
            System.out.println("Clicked Card: "+myId);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("mouse entered "+myId);
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("mouse exited"+myId);        
    }


    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {}


    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {}

}
```