# Image on Custom JComponent is not Visible?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcomponent

When I run my code it doesn't show up.
Basically I have a custom Jcomponent which I add to my JFrame or View and then create a View that makes the frame in my main method.
I already added to JFrame here is my code for the JComponent:

```
public class CardDisplay extends JComponent {
private Card card;
private Image cardImage;

public CardDisplay()
{
    cardImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(("Phase10//res//Blue2.png"));
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(cardImage, 125 ,200, this);
}
public class View {
public View(){

}

public void makeFrame()
{
   JFrame frame = new JFrame("Phase 10");
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   JPanel handPanel = new JPanel();
   CardDisplay cd = new CardDisplay();
   handPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
   frame.add(handPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   handPanel.add(cd);
   frame.pack();
   frame.setSize(600,500);
   frame.setResizable(false);
   frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    View view = new View();
    Game game = new Game();
    view.makeFrame();
    //game.run();

}
```

Comment: see my post http://stackoverflow.com/a/8422427/1007845

Comment: This is probably the problem in eventQueue when you starting your app. Add the lines of code which start application and creates CardDisplay.

Comment: @Adrian - Tried that but it still does not work

Comment: @Rendition try my other post on the same thread; I put it the entire code. It's probably paintComponent(..) and perhaps the way you add the component to your panels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the working version. The problem was mainly related to the preferred size of the component. Please note the implementation of method `getPreferredSize()`.

If you would like to see what are the component boundaries I'd recommend using [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) layout manager in debug mode (the site has all necessary documentation).

```
public class CardDisplay extends JComponent {
    private BufferedImage cardImage;

    public CardDisplay() {
        try {
            cardImage = ImageIO.read(new File("Phase10//res//Blue2.png"));
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(cardImage, 0, 0, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (cardImage == null) {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        } else {
            return new Dimension(cardImage.getWidth(null), cardImage.getHeight(null));
        }
    }

    public static class View {
        public View() {}

        public void makeFrame() {
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Phase 10");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            final JPanel handPanel = new JPanel();
            final CardDisplay cd = new CardDisplay();
            handPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            frame.add(handPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            handPanel.add(cd);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final View view = new View();
        view.makeFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented your code and it sends an Error stating it can't read the input file? I tried using ImageIO.read before i posted this and got the same thing. I've tried moving the file into the same folder as the Class to make sure the file extension was not a problem.

Comment: In a local project that I've have created for this code, it was simply "image.jpg", where the actual file was located at the base of the project.

Comment: what is final BufferedImage img = null; for?

Comment: @Rendition not needed -- just leftovers from when I was prototyping the example.

Comment: Okay well i've tried replacing the Image and it still cannot read the file. I've copied the exact code this time two... If it changes anything I'm working on a mac and my IDE is NetBeans

Comment: hm... try cardImage = ImageIO.read(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("logo.jpg")); where logo.jpg is on the project's classpath.

Comment: Now I'm geting IllegalArgumentException : Input = null!

Comment: This means that the image file is not on classpath and, thus it is not loaded.

Comment: :( but its in the same folder as the classes therefore the path should just be like "Blue2.jpg"? Edit: I got it to finally work but I have to put the Full path from /Users/user/Desktop/..../Blue2.jpg... really annoying TY so much for the help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8596/discussion-between-01es-and-rendition)

Comment: `g.drawImage(cardImage, 0, 0, null);` should be `g.drawImage(cardImage, 0, 0, this);`.

Answer (score 2):

For JComponents, you use paintComponent instead of paint. Paint is actually used to draw components while paintComponent is used to draw images.

Comment: Still did not paint after changing to paintComponent(Graphics g)

Comment: @Shawn Shroyer +1 for paintComponent()

Comment: +1 for telling paintComponent(...) for Swing, just override getPreferredSize() for the JComponent, as you doing paintComponent(), you will see what you want to see in the output.